# Follow/Unfollow button doesn't work when trying to unfollow using same ajax call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Scenario: page displays dynamically generated buttons(anchors) with a unique id for every button and a common class. Using the class I am retrieving the id in jquery and passing it to the controller for processing. While I am able to click the follow and change it to following, I am unable to toggle it back to follow. 
it gives me "server responded with a status of 500".

**ajax code**

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").on(
                    'click',
                    '.follow',
                    function(event) {
                        debugger;
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var cur = "#" + this.id;
                        var toFollow = {
                            "followeeID" : this.id
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            url : "../follow/add",
                            data : toFollow,
                            dataType : 'json',
                            type : "POST",
                            success : function(data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    console.log(cur);
                                    $(cur).removeClass("btn-default")
                                            .addClass("btn-success");
                                    $(cur).removeClass("follow").addClass(
                                            "follow");
                                    $(cur).html("Following");
                                } else {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    $(cur).addClass("btn-default")
                                            .removeClass("btn-success");
                                    $(cur).removeClass("follow").addClass(
                                            "follow");
                                    $(cur).html("Follow");
                                }

                            }
                        })

                    });

        });
```

**html code**

```
 <c:otherwise>
            <table class="table table-stripped table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${requestScope.userlist}" var="user">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${user.personID==sessionScope.user.personID}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${user.username}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${user.followers.contains(sessionScope.user)}">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${user.username}</td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-success unfollow" href="#"
                                    id="${user.personID}">Following</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${user.username}</td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-default follow" href="#"
                                    id="${user.personID}">Follow</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </c:otherwise>
```

**controller code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/follow/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public boolean addFollower(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String followeeID) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("reached controller");
    boolean flag = false;
    int id = Integer.parseInt(followeeID);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User follower = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    try {
        User followee = (User) followerDao.get(id);
        if (followee.getFollowers().contains(follower)) {
            followee.getFollowers().remove(follower);
            System.out.println("removed");
            flag=followerDao.removeFollower(followee);

        } else {
            followee.getFollowers().add(follower);
            System.out.println("added");
            flag=followerDao.addFollower(followee);

        }

    } catch (FollowerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag;

}
```

Comment: i am wondering what this line of code will do? `$(cur).removeClass("follow").addClass("follow");` remove class and add the same?

Comment: . that was actually adding  a .unfollow class when initially I was using two separate  classes and two separate controller functions, which weren't working so I didn't remove it then just changed that to follow. i later removed it but the copy which i uploaded contains that

Comment: ok, are you getting any js error in browser console when removing following? Also if you are getting server response as internal server error i.e. 500 then your removing follow code must have some issue, debug it

Comment: the only error that i get is when i do the second click for unfollow

Comment: currently i am not removing .follow class i am just sending to controller returning a boolean and on the basis of that my button changes. and yes i tried debugger but second time it doesnt go inside the $.ajax

Comment: i think i got the issue, let me add answer with code changes, added answer update your jquery code like below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` code inside `$(document).ready` function only works for available `DOM` elements when windows loaded successfully,

So, In order to make it work for dynamically added buttons, you should use event binding like below:

```
$(document).on(
    'click',
    '.follow',
    function(event) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        var cur = "#" + this.id;
        var toFollow = {
            "followeeID" : this.id
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : "../follow/add",
            data : toFollow,
            dataType : 'json',
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(cur);
                    $(cur).removeClass("btn-default")
                            .addClass("btn-success");
                    $(cur).removeClass("follow").addClass(
                            "follow");
                    $(cur).html("Following");
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    $(cur).addClass("btn-default")
                            .removeClass("btn-success");
                    $(cur).removeClass("follow").addClass(
                            "follow");
                    $(cur).html("Follow");
                }

            }
        })
    });
});
```

Make sure to sure use this jquery binding code outside `$(document).ready` function

Comment: I tried the above code but again it's giving me a 500 response from the server

Comment: if it is giving you server response error, then you have error at your server end which only you can debug.

Comment: so the ajax call is working perfectly right ? because iam unable to debug inside the the .ajax function

Comment: Yup, ajax is working fine that's why you are getting response as 500, also above answer will help you to trigger ajax second time and so on, after adding dynamic follow and following buttons